# Как обратиться к элементам объекта класса?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Не понимаю почему не получается получить значение singUp

```
router.get('/', async (request, response) => {

  let model = new Model();

  response.send(model.account.singUp);

}); 

function Model(){
}

Model.prototype.account = {
  singUp: 1,
  activate: 1
}
```

Не понимаю на что ругается, проблема точно не в методе send

```
express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead routers/others/test.js:12:12
***/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 1
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:194:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (***/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:185:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:754:10)
    at writeend (***/node_modules/express-session/index.js:261:22)
    at ontouch (***/node_modules/express-session/index.js:348:11)
    at Query._callback (***/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:254:17)
    at Query.Sequence.end (***/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (***/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.OkPacket (***/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:72:10)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (***/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (***/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (***/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (***/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:607:20)
```

Скажите возможно ли вообще обратиться так к элементам объекта?

Comment: [_The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array_](http://expressjs.com/ru/api.html#res.send) - ты же пытаешься послать число - и падаешь, потому что парсер думает ты хочешь статус отправить. Попробуй заменить `1` на `'1'`

Comment: Круто, теперь все ясно. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как указано в [описании](http://expressjs.com/ru/api.html#res.send):

> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array

> Параметр `body` может быть объектом `Buffer`, строкой, объектом или массивом

В данном случае передается число и идет попытка вызвать устаревшую перегрузку `send` отправляющую статус.

Для решения нужно отправлять либо сам объект `account`

```
response.send(model.account);
```

Либо хранить в полях объекта не числа, а строки:

```
singUp: '1'
```